# Introduction Limit point

Tags: general-topology

Actually my assignment topics are limit point and boundary point. 
But in introduction what should I write I have no any idea. Also please someone tell me how to write a good assignment.
all are with respect to topology

Comment: Of which type is your assignment? Do mean exercises or do you need to write some kind of essay?
Which kind of boundary point do mean? Boundary with respect to a topology or a metric?

Comment: boundary with respect to topology

Comment: For a better, more specific answer you have to give more specific questions. Just ask again if you have a concrete question or if you want more help to this problem specify your knowledge and your tasks.

Comment: If you would like to write questions that don't get closed, I would suggest that you go back to your earlier closed questions, and follow the suggestions that were already given to you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the norm in $\mathbb{R}^N$ be
$$
||x|| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2}.
$$
This is the length of the vector, $x$.  If you just want to do $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$, fill in the 2 and simplify the formula.

Define the open ball with radius $d$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ as
$$
B_d(x) = \{x':||x-x'||<d\}.
$$
Draw these for radii $1/2$, $1$ and $4$ at $x=(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, they all look like circles.

A set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ is open if is it a union of open balls. The open ball is always an open set. Try drawing a set on a piece of paper, and filling it with open balls.

A set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ is closed if the complement of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ is open. Draw the closed ball, $\overline{B}_d(x) = \{x':||x-x'|| \le \delta\}$.  How are $B_d(x)$ and $\overline{B}_d(x)$ different?  What is $\mathbb{R}^N \backslash \overline{B}_d(x)$, and is it a union of open balls?  Try drawing a picture.

A point $x$ of $S$ is a limit point of $S$ if, for any number $e>0$, there is an open ball of radius $e$ around $x$ that contains points of $S$. What are the limits points of the open ball?  The closed ball? (Hint: what points are missing from the open ball that are not missing from the closed ball?)

A point $x$ of $S$ is a boundary point of $S$ if, for any number $e>0$, there is an open ball of radius $e$ around $x$ that contains points in $S$ and also not in $S$. What are the boundary points of the open ball?  The closed ball?  Does a boundary point of $S$ have to be in $S$? (Hint: the boundary of the open and closed balls of radius $e$ are the same.)

It's nice to know that a set is closed if it contains all of its limit points.

Welcome to topology!

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you that [script](http://www.personal.psu.edu/axk29/TOPOLOGY/Chapter1.pdf) of A.Katok from PSU.

The basic concepts are enrolled in the first three pages with enough context to write an essay.

For writing a good math assignment I would always recommend using a [TeX-editor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Introduction), but that may be a lot of work if are not familiar with LateX at all.

Comment: The overhead to getting started with latex can be tremendous. One option is to use https://www.overleaf.com/ , so you don't have to worry about installing miktex or texlive, getting an IDE, etc.  My co-authors like it for projects, so everyone is using the same packages and we don't have to figure out how to get code to compile on each of our separate machines.